# Kafka partitions' have no leaders

Tags: apache-kafka

[image]

The specified topic is being used in an application.

- Does the topic effectively has only 3 partitions? So the applications producing data into this topic produce them inside these 3 partitions?
- Does the topic have 18 partitions, but the messages getting sent into the 15 leader-less partitions are in some limbo or getting lost?
- Finally, how can this be resolved.

I have tried looking around but i am not sure what are the cause and effects of so many partitions (15 out of 18) having no leader.

Comment: It would be helpful to post your config so we understand how your cluster is setup. In this case the partition assignment strategy would be one of the first places to look. https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs_partition.assignment.strategy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your image shows 18 partitions, not 3. The cluster will only *accept requests* to those 3 working topics with leaders, so "effectively", yes. However, Kafka producers hash data into **any partition** by default, and will not select only those with leaders.
2. The topic has replication factor of 1. Every `Leader: None` output means no data can be written to them, not only partition 15. In fact, partition 15 should be working, since it does have a leader.
3. You fix it by recovering the broker(s) where those partitions existed (perhaps Kafka process crashed on those machines?). Looks like you have a cluster of at least 9 brokers. Then, you can use `kafka-reassign-partitions.sh` to increase replication factor of that topic to at least 3 brokers.

Comment: I mean 15 partitions in total which dont have a leader , out of the 18 , and not partition number 15. So data being produced in those 15 partitions(with no leader), is getting lost?

Comment: Your producers should be throwing errors when trying to send data to those partitions, and dropping events, yes